# Passing an image from a Wep Api service to another Web Api service

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

For security reasons, I am building two Web Api services. The first Web Api app will have access to an image generating service, and will act as a security proxy. The second Web Api app will call the first app from the internet and retrieve the image.

However, I can't seem to get to negotiate passage of the image correctly. My thought was to have the security proxy Web API to get the image, and then pass it as a byte array my other service which would allow a user to download the image. However, when my browser attempts to open the image, it is always corrupted.

Here is the security proxy getting the image, which I know is successful:

```
public byte[] Get(string invoice, string Customer)
    {
        object image;
        try
        {
            image = _repo.GetImage(invoice, Customer);
        }
        catch (ApplicationException exc)
        {
            var resp = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
            {
                Content = new StringContent(string.Format("No Image with Invoice Number = {0}", invoice.ToString())),
                ReasonPhrase = "Image Not Found"
            };
            throw new HttpResponseException(resp);
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotFound));

        }
        return (byte[])image;
    }
```

This returns an array with a length of 40133.

The calling Web API service looks like this:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get(string invoice, string Customer)
    {           

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/octet-stream"));

        byte[] img = client.GetByteArrayAsync("http://localhost:1363/api/Image/" + invoice + "/" + Customer).Result;

        HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();
        response.Content = new ByteArrayContent(img);
        response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/tiff");
        var disposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
        disposition.FileName = "ImageDocument.tif";
        response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = disposition;

        return response;

    }
```

However, the length of the img byte array is 53514.

When the browser tries to open the image, it tells me it is corrupt. If I open the TIFF in notepad, I get :

```
"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
```

***SNIP****

Anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

Chris

**Solved**

If anyone is interested in the calling code that leverages the solution identified, here it is:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get(string invoice, string Customer)
    {

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("image/tiff"));

        byte[] img = client.GetByteArrayAsync("http://localhost:1363/api/Image/" + invoice + "/" + Customer).Result;

        HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();
        response.Content = new ByteArrayContent(img);
        response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/tiff");
        var disposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
        disposition.FileName = "ImageDocument.tif";
        response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = disposition;

        return response;


    }
```

Comment: Why not just pass the URL of the image instead of the bytes?

Comment: The image is generated on the fly, and the calling Web Api service doesn't have privileges to access the generation function itself, hence the need for the security proxy Web API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your above current return type (byte[]) of action, formatters of web api are probably handling them and hence you are seeing unexpected response.

can you try sending the image as a ByteArrayContent instead?(you need to have HttpResponseMessage as a return type here)

Example:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
response.Content = new ByteArrayContent(..your byte array here...);
response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/jpeg");

return response;
```

Comment: And how would I work with the response from the calling Web API?

Comment: your above code of reading the response should be fine in this case too.